# Spring Cloud Contract - is there a possibility to verify a zoned date time?

Tags: datetimeoffset, spring-cloud-contract

I have a contract with a timestamp in ZonedDateTime format (e.g. 2016-11-16T02:12:45.000+0000). The contract was converted from a Pact file.

The generated test seems to check only timestamps without zones. For example:

```
...
assertThat(parsedJson.read("$.activation", String.class)).matches("([0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])");
...
```

Is it at all possible to validate zoned timestamps? Or is that only not working for pact translated contracts?

Comment: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-11-16T02:12:45.000+0000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx"))`. If it throws a `DateTimeParseException`, validation has failed.

Comment: I meant the regex check Spring Cloud contract verifier generates in its test classes when it encounters a timestamp in a contract. The regex looks as if only date and time are expected, but without zone information. I was wondering how I can tell SCC that the pattern contains a zone or if it alway expected iso dates withouth zones.

Comment: Obviously you can. It seems your offset is either a plus or a minus followed by four digits. If you want stricter validation, the first digit should be 0 or 1, and the third should be less than 6. If you want more lenient validation, there may be 2, 4 or 6 digits, and there may or may not be a colon between every 2, for example `+00:00`. For all the details see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (since your timestamp is in this format).

Comment: You can provide your own regex and that way state what you want to assert